# What is the set number for these Star Wars parts?

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

We lost the majority of my son's Lego collections in a flood. The attached pictures are all we have and need them identified for insurance.

[image]

Would appreciate your help identifying the set number.

Comment: This is mostly the Space Police Galactic Enforcer Set LEGO #5974.  Which Star Wars parts are you referring to?  Can you point them out in the picture?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This was my best guess on the parts that went together.  Others are likely lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have (part of) set [5974 - Galactic Enforcer (2009)](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=5974-1). This set is missing a few parts, as the back end is supposed to be rather symmetrical and there is a separate space ship (black). See the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. This was my best guess on the parts that went together. Others are likely lost.

Comment: No problem Tom ... and so sorry to hear about what happened - hope the insurance covers enough to purchase some nice replacement sets!

Comment: We hope the insurance covers them.  I have several more to identify - since I am new to this site I am not sure the best way to post the pictures of the rest.  Any advice?  Thanks

Comment: You can put multiple pictures in one post and ask for identification of all of them. Alternatively, if you know your way around LEGO pieces and can identify some unique ones per set (e.g. with special stickers, or unusual shape) you can use the Catalog Items search on [BrickLink](http://www.bricklink.com) to find which sets they appear in, that way you don't have to ask .... but there are many of us here who like the challenge :)